# Could not find com.zendesk:support-providers:5.0.2

Tags: android, azure-devops, continuous-integration, zendesk, zendesk-sdk

Well I just tried to generate an Android APK in my Azure DevOps pipeline and it gives me the following error, does any one have solved this issue?, all works fine the same build varian in Android Studio, also before adding this dependency in my pipeline works fine.

```
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/home/vsts/work/1/s/ProjectFolder/module01/libs/support-providers-5.0.2.jar
       - file:/home/vsts/work/1/s/ProjectFolder/module01/libs/support-providers.jar
     Required by:
         project :module01 > project :module02 > project :module03
```

UPDATE - even the most basic pipeline fails to resolve dependencies.

I change the dependency and instead using providers I am using support sdk

```
implementation "com.zendesk:support:5.0.2"
```

And returns an error too.

```
Could not find com.zendesk:support:5.0.2.
```

This is my basic pipeline.

```
# Start of the pipeline
# Android
# Build your Android project with Gradle.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute the APK, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/android

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: 'CustomFolder'
    gradleWrapperFile: 'CustomFolder/gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'assembleDevelopment'

# End of the pipeline
```

Comment: Can you share your configuration of your pipeline? Please also follow the steps in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops) and share the complete logs with us. In addition, which agent are you using? Please try to use a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved it adding the repository into all projects in project build.gradle file.

```
// build.gradle file (project)

allprojects {

    repositories {

        // other repositories...

        maven {

            url "https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo"
        }
    }
}
```